# How to work with JPA and the Entity Object Life Cycle

Tags: java, jpa, entity, eclipselink

I'm working on a simple Surveysystem using JPA Eclipselink, and I'm quite new at this (JPA and databases) so I'm not sure which approach I should take.

The way I've done things so far is using a DAO-class for all the database-logic, and all my entity-relations are (hopefully) annotated correctly.

My Teacher-entity can have multiple surveys, and each Survey-entity can have multiple questions. This is how I've got the relation-annotations looking:

**Teacher.java**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Survey> surveys = new ArrayList<Survey>();
```

**Survey.java**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "teacherid", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Teacher teacher;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "survey", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

**Question.java**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "surveyid", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Survey survey;
```

In each class, I've got an addSometing()-method like this:
`survey.addQuestion(q)`

```
public void addQuestion(Question q) {
    if (q != null) {
        q.setSurvey(this);
        questions.add(q);
    }
}
```

And then, finally, another addSomething()-method for each entity in my DAO which looks like this:

```
public void addSurvey(Survey survey) {

    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();

    try {
        tx.begin();
        em.persist(survey);
        tx.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        if (tx.isActive()) {
            tx.rollback();
        }

    } finally {
        em.close();
    }

}
```

When I run my code, I manage to create and add a Teacher-object to the database just fine. Then I create a Question-object and add this to a new Survey-object and add this to my Teacher which works fine as well. But when I then try to persist my Question and Survey objects to the database and merge/update the Teacher-object I get an InvalidStateException:

```
Encountered unmanaged object "no.hib.dat104.obl3.model.Survey@52892ae7" in life cycle state  unmanaged while cascading persistence via field "no.hib.dat104.obl3.model.Question.survey" during flush.  However, this field does not allow cascade persist. You cannot flush unmanaged objects or graphs that have persistent associations to unmanaged objects.
```

I don't think the way I'm doing these things is the correct way to work with JPA entities. Could anyone give me a short explanation about how I really should do this or point me in the right direction? I know about the [Entity Object Life Cycle](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/managed), but I'm not sure about how to approach this in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EntityManager context you are obtaining within the addSurvey method is new and so empty.  Presumably when you persist the survey, it has questions and a teacher assigned.  In your model, the teacher instance is an existing object in the database and the reference from Survey to Teacher has no cascade options- JPA is required to throw an exception when it comes across an unmanaged object in the model, as it doesn't know what you intend to do with it.

There are many ways to deal with this in your model, but they depend on many other external factors.  The quickest solution I can think of is to just change things slightly so that the teacher ManyToOne reference is using the `cascade = CascadeType.Merge` option, and then use `em.merge(survey);` in the addSurvey method.  JPA will then determine that the survey and questions are new and insert them, while it will merge any changes in the existing Teacher instance into the database.

There are many other options though such as using an extended persistence unit that can be used to read in the Teacher instance as well as persist your Survey and Question instances.  What is best for your application depends on what you expect to happen under different circumstances.

Comment: I see. My teacher at school told me to have one EntityManager for each HTTP-session. The way I've done this now is by initializing a new EM when someone logs in and close it when they log out/the session expires. This fixed my errors, but how does this method compare to your proposed method?

Comment: That is equivalent to what I suggested at the end, of having an extended persistence context - it works and is a common approach.  It means that you keep everything around a bit longer, as everything read in through an EntityManager stays in memory until it is closed or cleared.  As long as this doesn't happen, everything remains managed.  You still need to look at and deal with merging things that you might have serialized or read back from the client though.